# Simulate onClick event in enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have this code in my `Search` component render method:

```
   <button className="searchButton" onClick={this.handleSearch}>{this.state.on ? 'Search' : null}</button>
```

and then I have this:

```
  handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      on: !prevState.on
    }));
  }
```

this definitely gets called when I click the button. however, my test is not simulating it even though I feel like I am doing it the correct way.

```
it.only('calls handleSearch', () => {
  searchButton = renderedOutput.find('button').at(0);
  searchButton.simulate('click');
  expect(handleSearchStub).to.have.been.called;
});
```

however, for some reason it does not think that my function has been called even though surely that is the way to simulate it? (there is only one button on the page)

Comment: just `.click() ` like in normal dom ?

Comment: @MaciejKozieja where are you referring to?

Comment: It would be good to see how you are passing the stub to the component in your test, as the onClick handler is a method not a passed in function prop, and `handleSearch` method doesnt call any passed in function prop either. I can only presume you are spying on the `handleSearch` method itself?

Comment: @alechill the only thing I have done is: `    handleSearchStub = sinon.stub();` set it up as a sinon stub

Comment: Then you would need to pass it into the component. I think a stub is the wrong approach anyway here, as your method does not call anything external that you would need to pass in as a stub. Testing internal method calls is too tied to implementation details. Instead test the end result...

I would simulate the click, then assert that the state has in fact changed either by `expect(renderedOutput.state().on).to.be.true` OR the end result of this state ie that the button has text in it `expect(renderedOutput.find('button').at(0).text()).to.be.equal('Search')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is enzyme considers handle search method as a constant.
Try something like this. it should work

```
handleSearch(e){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      on: !prevState.on
    }));
  }

 <button className="searchButton" onClick={(e) => this.handleSearch(e)}>{this.state.on ? 'Search' : null}</button>
```

Comment: This would have identical behaviour, except as the onClick handler is now an anonymous function, it will cause a re-render of the button component every time even if nothing else has changed.

In this component as its just a small button then that will likely have no real performance impact, but if this was done higher up the tree, it can cripple performance. One to keep an eye out for

Comment: yeah that's true. So i usually bind function once in constructor and call it. that way will address the problem.

Comment: Yep good plan, the way the OP does it also works instead of binding in constructor, as they have used an arrow function when defining the method, so is already bound to the lexical `this`, scoping to the class